# Sort array along with labels

Tags: matlab, sorting, graph, plot, bar-chart

I have a question about bar graph in Matlab.

I have this,

```
a=[20 86 3];
```

but each number corresponds to one letter like,

```
20 -->a
86 -->b
3  -->c
```

and then I make the bar graph,

```
bar(a)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'a','b','c'})
```

Is there a way to sort `a` but keep the letter that corresponds to each number?

I thought making a dictionary but I don't know how to make it in MATLAB

Thank you.

Comment: Big project to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
a = [20 86 3];
l = {'a' , 'b' , 'c'};
[a,ind] = sort(a);
l = l(ind);
```

When you use `[a,ind] = sort(a);` the sorted `a` will be saved in `a` and the indexes will be saved in `ind`, which can be used to sort `l` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand (I'm new at MATLAB). What does it mean "[~,ind]"? And how the bar graph is finally made? Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: `[~,ind] = sort(a)` means to ignore the first output of function `sort`, which is the sorted `a` but we need that.